# How shall we prove electric field is negative gradient of potential in case of an arbitrary charge distribution?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

In schools we learn about electric field of point charge being negative gradient of potential. From this how can we generalize it for charge distributions? Any proof will be appreciated.

Comment: About the negative: that is just a convention, we notice that in electrostatic $rot \bf{E} = 0$ and from that we deduce that the electrostatic field derive from a potential, we usually write it $\bf{E}=-\nabla \phi$ but nobody prevent me from defining $f=-\phi$ and from that writing   $\bf{E}= \nabla $$f$calling $f$ the potential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the principle of superposition: you can imagine an arbitrary charge distribution as the superposition of infinitesimal point charges.
$$
\rho (\textbf{x}) = \sum dq_i\, \delta(\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}_i)
$$ Therefore the potential of the distribution is the sum (possibly the integral) of the potentials due to every single charge:
$$
V(\textbf{x}) = \sum V_i(\textbf{x}) \,\,\,\left(= \frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\textbf{x}')}{|\textbf{x} - \textbf{x}'|} d^3x'\right)
$$
 Since the sum of the gradient is the gradient of the sum,
$$
\textbf{E(x)} = \sum \textbf{E}_i(\textbf{x}) = \sum \left( - \nabla V_i(\textbf{x}) \right) = - \nabla \left(\sum V_i(\textbf{x})\right) = - \nabla V(\textbf{x})
$$
 you have shown that the electric field of a charge ditribution is the negative gradient of its potential.